# Dropdownmenu's linked?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, criteria

I've got a first dropdown menu (tableform) having the letters A,B,C... , secondly I have a dropdownmenu with in tableform as well (so you can't type any wrong words) for instance Bird, Beast, ..., Duc...
What I want is that the second dropdownmenu is just concentrated to the first letter I choose. How do You do that?

Comment: You could Google "Access cascading combo box" and get lots of different solutions -- it's a really frequently-asked question.

Answer (score 1):

In the after update of the first combo box, go:

```
Dim Sql as string

Sql = "select Animal from tblAnimals where Animal like '" & me.combo1 & "*'"
Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = sql
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I'll try this rightaway. Greetings to You and Your Family and a great 2011. (thanks for helping me out.)

Comment: 'Like' can be a little slow if you have a large recordset, select Animal from tblAnimals where left(Animal,1)='" & me.combo1 & "'" might be faster.

Comment: With Jet/ACE, LIKE will always be faster than selecting on the result of a VBA function or UDF because LIKE will use the index when the pattern is at the beginning of the field. I don't know if it would be faster if the pattern was being matched anywhere in the field, but I'd suspect it would be, since it could do a tablescan without needing to execute a function for each row.